# Keep object centre fixed whilst size changes

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a circle that expands using CSS keyframes, with fixed positioning. The trouble is, as the circle changes size, the centre of the circle moves (whilst the top left corner remains fixed). How do I ensure the centre is fixed during the animation? Is there a way to specify the "origin" of the div so that's it's not the top left?

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

and

```
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  background: #07F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: expand linear 3s infinite;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dayyg4h4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, what you can do is use `transform - scale` property to increase dimensions  and then `transform-origin` to keep it centered:

```css
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  background: #07F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: expand linear 3s infinite alternate;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help U @BinaryFunt

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```css
#circle {
  position: fixed;
  background: #07F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: expand linear 3s infinite alternate;
  top: calc(10px + 50px); /* 10px + (half of the initial height) */
  left: calc(10px + 50px); /* 10px + (half of the initial width) */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Nice one I was thinking on that negative translate but was missing the `calc` part for the position +1

Comment: Actually I ended up switching to this method as I later added a border to the circle, and the scale transform pixelates the border and changes its thickness